# AChartEngine bar graph scrolling beyond the Y Axis

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm using AChartEngine library for plotting graphs in my application. In the implementation of the Bar Graph, I've enabled the horizontal pan. Also, I'm displaying the graph in a Relative layout of one of my activity. Problem is that, when I scroll horizontally towards Y axis, bars travel beyond Y axis, which appears to be very awkward. Code is shown below.

```
public GraphicalView setTheBarGraph(String title) {
        String[] titles = new String[] { "WiFi", "Mobile Network" };
        int[] colors = new int[] { Color.rgb(51, 102, 153),
                Color.rgb(153, 51, 102) };
        double[] limits = new double[] { 0, 12, 0, 0 };
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = buildBarRenderer(colors);
        if (title.equals("Month"))
            setChartSettings(renderer, "", title, "Usage" + "(" + monthSize
                    + ")", 0, usageValues.size() + 1, 0, totalMax,
                    Color.rgb(108, 122, 125), Color.rgb(108, 122, 125));
        else if (title.equals("Day"))
            setChartSettings(renderer, "", title,
                    "Usage" + "(" + daySize + ")", 0, usageValues.size() + 1,
                    0, totalMax, Color.rgb(108, 122, 125),
                    Color.rgb(108, 122, 125));
        renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(0).setDisplayChartValues(true);
        renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(1).setDisplayChartValues(true);
        renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(0).setChartValuesTextSize(18);
        renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(1).setChartValuesTextSize(18);
        renderer.setPanLimits(limits);
        renderer.setXLabels(0);
        renderer.setYLabels(12);
        for (int i = 0; i < monthList.size(); i++) {
            renderer.addXTextLabel(i + 1, monthList.get(i));
        }
        renderer.setInScroll(true);
        renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT);
        renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
        renderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.rgb(108, 122, 125));
        renderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.rgb(108, 122, 125));
        renderer.setXLabelsPadding(5);
        renderer.setYLabelsPadding(5);
        renderer.setPanEnabled(true, false);
        renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
        renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        renderer.setMarginsColor(Color.argb(0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01));
        renderer.setZoomEnabled(false);
        renderer.setYLabelsAngle(20);
        // renderer.setZoomRate(1.1f);
        renderer.setBarSpacing(0.5);
        return ChartFactory.getBarChartView(mbcContext,
                buildBarDataset(titles, usageValues), renderer, Type.DEFAULT);
    }

    protected void setChartSettings(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer,
            String title, String xTitle, String yTitle, double xMin,
            double xMax, double yMin, double yMax, int axesColor,
            int labelsColor) {
        renderer.setChartTitle(title);
        renderer.setXTitle(xTitle);
        renderer.setYTitle(yTitle);
        renderer.setXAxisMin(xMin);
        renderer.setXAxisMax(xMax);
        renderer.setYAxisMin(yMin);
        renderer.setYAxisMax(yMax);
        renderer.setAxesColor(axesColor);
        renderer.setLabelsColor(labelsColor);
        renderer.setMargins(new int[] { 35, 60, 30, 20 });
    }

    protected XYMultipleSeriesDataset buildBarDataset(String[] titles,
            List<double[]> values) {
        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        int length = titles.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries(titles[i]);
            double[] v = values.get(i);
            int seriesLength = v.length;
            for (int k = 0; k < seriesLength; k++) {
                series.add(v[k]);
            }
            dataset.addSeries(series.toXYSeries());
        }
        return dataset;
    }

    protected XYMultipleSeriesRenderer buildBarRenderer(int[] colors) {
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(22);
        renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(22);
        renderer.setLabelsTextSize(17);
        renderer.setLegendTextSize(22);
        int length = colors.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
            r.setColor(colors[i]);
            renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
        }
        return renderer;
    }
```

I've uploaded a snapshot of this problem. Please help.

[image]

Comment: please add the latest version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after two days of breaking my head, I finally figured out the problem.

```
renderer.setMarginsColor(Color.argb(0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01));
```

The above code, sets the margin color to be transparent. This causes the bar's to be visible even after axis lines. This is quite unacceptable. Bars should not travel beyond axis lines regardless of the margin color.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using an old version of AChartEngine. I suggest you upgrade to the latest version 1.2.0.

Comment: R u saying that this problem exists in the previous versions?? I'm currently using 1.1.0 version.

Comment: These kind of problems exist in the previous versions? I'm using 1.1.0 version. Is 1.2.0 an official release or a testing release?

Comment: It's a nightly build.

Comment: I updated the version. There were few changes that I had to make after updating. Still, the problem persists. I could not figure out the reason. The X Axis label disappears soon after crossing the Y Axis but not the bar.

Comment: You created a transparent background, that is probably the problem.

Comment: How come X Axis label disappears? As you can observe in the snapshot, U cannot see the label of the bar that has exceeded the Y Axis. I'm breaking my head here, some help please.

Comment: I still see the X axis labels.

Comment: U can observe the bar which is outside Y Axis. Its displaying o.17 value. Where is the X Label for it. There should be a date below that bar.

Answer (score -2):

Have you try it `renderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);`

Comment: @Abhijith U cannot scroll the graph without enabling "renderer.setPanEnabled".